# Why using if in this way is preventing it from running

Tags: c++, visual-studio, if-statement, visual-c++

so here the if inside the loop is it possible to write the if statement in an optimized way or should I just split the two conditions?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int grade, counter = 1, total = 0, average;

    while (counter <= 10)
    {
        cout << "Enter grade /100: ";
        cin >> grade;

        if (grade < 0 && grade > 100) //HERE PLEASE
        {
            cout << "invalid grade value." << endl;
            cout << "Reenter grade value */100*: ";
            cin >> grade;
        }
        
        total = total + grade;

        counter++;
    }
    
    average = total / 10;
    
    cout << "\nThe class average is:  " << average << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't tag this a "c", please read the comments for the tags you're about to apply first!

Comment: A little help from [your rubber duck](https://rubberduckdebugging.com/) would have helped

Comment: Hint for the OP:   Your program is testing if  `grade`  is negative and also `grade` is greater than 100.    There are relatively few values that are both negative and greater than 100 at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```cpp
if (grade < 0 && grade > 100)
```

There is no number that is lower than `1` ***and*** bigger than `100`, so that conditions will return `false` every time.

If you want lower than `1` ***or*** bigger than `100`, try:

```cpp
if (grade < 0 || grade > 100)
```

Overall, your code should be:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
// using namespace std; is bad practice, so don't use it

int main()
{
    int grade = 0, counter = 1, total = 0, average = 0;

    while (counter <= 10)
    {
        std::cout << "Enter grade /100: ";
        std::cin >> grade;

        if (grade < 0 || grade > 100) 
        {
            // use newline character instead of std::endl
            std::cout << "invalid grade value." << '\n'; 
            std::cout << "Reenter grade value */100*: ";
            std::cin >> grade;
        }
        // a = a + b is equal to a += b
        total += grade;

        ++counter;
    }
    
    average = total / 10;
    
    std::cout << "\nThe class average is:  " << average << '\n'; 

    return 0;
}
```